# C# RedOS не запускается приложение, собранное в Avalonia

Tags: c#, avalonia

в Visual Studio поставил расширение Avalonia, приложение опубликовал как linux-x64, в RedOS оно пытается его загрузить, но приложение не появляется... .Net SDK установил.

Comment: Исключение какое? Текст нужен

Comment: В этом и проблема, что и узнать ничего не получается - каких-либо ошибок не выводит. Только анимация курсора (загрузки), которая после 5 секунд заканчивается без каких-либо дальнейших действий.

Answer (score 0):

Решение простое, в терминале написал [путь к файлу] dotnet run - запускается.